# Symbol's function definition is void: x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value

Tags: emacs

Just installed Emacs 24 under Windows 7

Getting the following error when trying to cut & paste (kill & yank) within emacs, e.g.

```
C-k, C-y
```

to kill a line and copy it somewhere else:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value
```

I have commented out the following from my .emacs and restarted emacs but error remains:

```
;; get copy and paste to work between emacs and other windows
;; (setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
;; (setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)
```

I have no similar problems using emacs 24 with the same .emacs file under linux

I have done an initial googel trawl but all the information I found suggest the bug has been fixed already which isn't much help

Unfortunately, this is making emacs unusable under windows for me

**UPDATE**

this line doesn't seem to be causing the problem:

```
;; get copy and paste to work between emacs and other windows
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

however these lines do:

```
;; this line causes cut/paste errors under windows (emacs 24)
;; (setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)

;; this alternative fixes windows problems but causes errors under linux (emacs 24)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-selection-value)
```

I have had a go at making my .emacs platform conditional, e.g.:

```
;; this line causes cut/paste errors under windows (emacs 24)
(if (eq system-type 'gnu-linux) (setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value) )
;; (setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)

;; this alternative causes errors under linux (emacs 24)
(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt) (setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-selection-value) )
;;(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-selection-value)
```

this fixes the problem but this seems like a bit of a kludge...

Comment: If you are trying alpha, please go to stable one* (emacs 24.1), It seems recent changes broke the cl pkg and lexical stuff..

Comment: @kindahero - using emacs-24.1-bin-i386 precompiled binaries

Comment: Same problem still in emacs-24.2 for Windows.  Thanks a bunch for this solution. Horrible not having paste command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does Emacs behave if you didn't customize at all?  i.e. start with

```
emacs -Q
```

?

I don't have Windows machine in front of me, but there nothing in my config that's Windows specific for cut/paste, and I never had any problems with 24, although I haven't tried the stable release yet.

Comment: yes - the answer is to delete the lot as running emacs -Q works on both platforms, I did this and then re-evaluated the buffer but should have restarted emacs

Answer (score 9):

The variable name changed in EMACS 24:

`current-kill: Symbol's function definition is void: x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value`

Open your .emacs and change:
'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)

to:
`(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-selection-value)`

I found the answer in this posting:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2010-09/msg00638.html

Comment: i don't think you read the update to the OP? you've just restated the Windows solution